# How do I randomize sampling output of char-rnn?

Tags: lua, torch, recurrent-neural-network

Whenever I sample, I get the same results for a given temperature value. Is there a way to configure a random seed or another value that controls the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `math.randomseed(os.time())` once at the start of the program.